Having trouble with this series involving absolute value
"let x, y, and z be real numbers such that $|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|=100$. What is the maximum value of $|x-y|$?"
At first, I thought it might be 100, since that's the literal maximum value of the possible difference between x and y. But someone pointed out that for this answer to be true, $|y-z|$ and $|z-x|$ must both be $0$, meaning $y=z=x$, so $x=y$, and $|x-y|=0$.
There's also a follow up questions-
"Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... , a_{10}$ be real numbers such that $|a_1-a_2|+|a_2-a_3|+|a_3-a_4|+|a_4-a_5|+...+|a_9-a_{10}|+|a_{10}-a_1|=500$.
What is the largest possible value of $|a_1-a_6|$?"
This one feels more complicated/different- in the first problem, its the absolute value of each number subtract the next number, and then the last term is the last number subtract the first number, whereas this is the first number (a1) subtract a number in the middle of the series ($a_6$).
Also, what are some key words I can look up to learn more about this
Thanks!

A series is an infinite sum. None of the sums in your problem are infinite.

These problems are more geometric visualization problems than mathematical analysis problems.
For the 1st problem, the three values form the sides of a triangle whose perimeter is $~100.~$  Therefore, the max value of a given side is $~50,~$ which represents a degenerate triangle whose area has gone to $~0.~$
For the 2nd problem, you can assume, without loss of generality that $~a_6 = a_7 = a_8 = a_9 = a_{10}.~$  So, it is as if you have that
$$|a_1 - a_2| + \cdots + |a_5 - a_6| + |a_6 - a_1| = 500.$$
So, you have a hexagon, with a perimeter of $~500,~$ and setting $~|a_1 - a_6| = 250~$ turns it into a degenerate hexagon whose area is $~0.$

Think of $x, y$ and $z$ on a number line.  One of them is on the left, one on the right, the other in the middle.  The sum of the three differences is twice the difference between the two ends.

You say pot$\overline{a}$to, I say pot$a^{!!!!^{\cup}}$to.
